# Python regex re.findall() returns only one match

Tags: python, regex

I have got a feature string like:

[...]

'    user1 DESKTOP DISPLAY (v38) (SERVER/PORT 1001), start Thu 10/17 6:40\n',

'    user2 DESKTOP DISPLAY  (v38) (SERVER/PORT 1501), start Thu 10/17 6:49\n',

'    user3 DESKTOP DISPLAY  (v38) (SERVER/PORT 2602), start Thu 10/17 8:33\n',

'    user4 DESKTOP DISPLAY  (v40) (SERVER/PORT 2702), start Thu 10/17 8:44\n'

[...]

I am trying to return all users with relevant data by using a regular expression and the `.findall()` function:

```
            # Check user details
            regexLicenseUser = re.compile(
                r"    (\S+) (.+) (.+) \(v(\S+)\) \((\S+)/(\d+) (\d+)\)"
                r", start \w+ (\d+)/(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)")

            # Get all users per feature
            Users = re.findall(regexLicenseUser, features)
```

Afterwards I want to group relevant data into columns (per user)

```
            for LicUser in Users:
                User = LicUser[0]
                Desktop = LicUser[1]
                ...
```

And then return it as a list:

```
            sessionInfo = [User, Desktop, ...]
```

This unfortunately only returns one match, I need to return (in this case) four matches. Does anybody know how to proceed on that?

Comment: You need to convert the features into a string say something like "".join(features) and then improve your regexLicenceUser to capture all the groups of data that you need. Alternatively, you can loop through your features and make the regexLicenceUser get the data on a feature. What data do you wish to get from a feature?

Comment: Your second proposal is what I am trying to do: First I get the name of the feature, how many users can use it in total and how many really use the feature. Then I would like to return the users who are using a specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the features are a list. If so, Findall will find matches only in the first element of the list. You need to consolidate all features into a single string that can be searched, or create a loop to run findall iteratively over each element of the list. Findall won't iterate over elements in a list.

Comment: My fault, the features are listed in a string. That is why I use ```.findall()``` instead of ```.search()```.